# ITextSharp PDF is not being printed correctly

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext

I have a a pdf Which I created using ITextSharp. I set the PageSize to A6 and when rendered with acrobat it's being shown correctly. However when I print It's only taking about 1/10 of the page. the printer is Zebra TLP 2844

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds more like a printer issue than a PDF one.  Can we see the PDF?

Comment: I solved it. I was passing the wrong arguments to Acrobat! But still thanks

Comment: Then you should answer yourself and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat's printing arguments should be: /P /H